# Comparação de um edttext com um valor do Banco SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, comparação

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em android mas não sei com impedir que o usuário cadastre dois horários iguais.

Banco:

```
 String sql4 ="CREATE TABLE "+TABELAAGE+"("
                +IDAGE+ " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                +NOMECLIAGE+ " text not null,"
                +DATA+ " text not null,"
                +HORA+ " text not null,"
                +SERVICO+ " text not null,"
                        +VALOR+ " text not null"
                +")";
```

Não posso deixar o usuário marcar dois horários iguais na mesma data

Comment: Olá! Você adicionou o campo DATA como text certo? como você salva este campo? Qual o formato? Você não quer permitir uma data identica?

Comment: Sim, pode existir duas datas identicas mas não dois horarios identicos na mesma data

Answer (score 1):

Para isto, é necessário realizar uma consulta!

Esta irá retornar o `ID` (se houver) um objeto com a mesma `DATA` e `HORA`!

Se não houver nenhum registro, este método irá retornar `-1`

```
    public Integer validarData(final String DATA, final String HORA){

        final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        final Cursor cursor = db.query(TABELAAGE, new String[]{"id"}, "DATA = ? AND HORA =?", new String[]{DATA, HORA}, null, null, null, null);
       //se nulo ou vazio não encontrou nenhum com a mesma data e hora, retorna -1
        if (null == cursor || !cursor.moveToFirst()) return -1;

        final Integer id = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return id;
    }
```

Se estiver alterando o Objeto, verifique se o `ID` retornado é igual ao ID do objeto.

Segue :

```
  public void validar(){
        Integer idComDataEHora = validarData("01/12/2016", "17:18:19");
        if(idComDataEHora.equals(-1)){
            // não exite nenhum registro
        }else{
            /// Se vc está editando, verifique se o id é igual ao que está editando!

        }

    }
```

Comment: No caso no lugar das interrogações coloco as editTexts?? E no botão inserir chamo a função?

Comment: função n , o metodo "validardata"

Comment: E estou tendo um erro na linha "final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();" diz q n pode encontrar o metodo

Comment: Na ação do botão você chama o **validar** ! Este por sua vez irá chamar o  **validarData(DATA, HORA)**. No logar do **DATA** e **HORA**, coloque os campos que vem do EditText.

Comment: O método **getWritableDatabase()** vem de  **SQLiteOpenHelper**. Segue um exemplo: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: no caso eu crio o banco em uma classe separada da que eu faço o insert

Comment: Na mesma classe!

Comment: public  Integer validarData(final String DATA, final String HORA){

        SQLiteDatabase db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
        final Cursor cursor = db.query(banco.TABELAAGE, new String[]{"id"}, "DATA = ? AND HORA =?", new String[]{Dia.getText().toString(), Hora.toString()}, null, null, null, null);
        //se nulo ou vazio não encontrou nenhum com a mesma data e hora, retorna -1
        if (null == cursor || !cursor.moveToFirst()) return -1;

        final Integer id = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return id;
    }

Comment: ficou assim,mas estou tendo outro erro java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.userlocal.oficinadocabelo.banco.banco.getWritableDatabase()' on a null object reference

Comment: é provável que o **banco** esteja nulo! Seria interessante criar uma nova pergunta, aí fica mais fácil de ajudar!

Comment: pronto ja criei

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169995/compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-edittext-com-valor-do-banco2